# Azure AD Intranet Login Portal

Tags: php, azure, authentication, portal, intranet

I'm trying to make an Intranet page for staff they authenticate into to see personalized information.

I'm currently trying to use Azure AD App registrations and PHP. I have the following code so far then I become stuck:

```
<a href="https://login.microsoftonline.com/website.co.uk/oauth2/authorize?client_id=xyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxz&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://website2.com/login/authentication&response_mode=query&state=12345&resource=Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory">LOGIN</a>
```

Then:

```
$get_code = $_GET['code'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/website.co.uk/oauth2/token',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
        "client_id" => "xyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxzxyzxyzyxz",
        "code" => $get_code,
        "redirect_uri" => "https://website2.com/login/authentication",
        "client_secret" => "hgdfyuieshafguirhuiqagfhuirehguirej",
        "resource" => "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory"
    )
));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

This all seem to work and I get an Access token back.

In the Required permissions on Azure AD it just has the default:

"Windows Azure Active Directory (Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory) /
Sign in and read user profile"

I'm also requesting the "resource" as "Microsoft.Azure.ActiveDirectory". Is this resource correct and how do I now read the users profile? Thanks

Comment: The resource should be `https://graph.windows.net` for Azure AD Graph API.

Comment: @juunas Hi, I'm trying to use:

CURLOPT_URL => 'https://graph.windows.net/me?api-version=1.6',
CURLOPT_HEADER => 1,
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Authorization" => "Bearer hfeyusgufygrsuygfuydsguy",
    "Content-Type" => "application/json"

This does not seem to work and I get:
"Access Token missing or malformed."